# How can I terminate a tkinter mainloop from a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have the following problem: I would like to create a GUI with tkinter, that reacts to signals, sent from a socket. For example, I would like to be able to terminate the application, when an *end* signal is received.

For that purpose I have a function, running in a separate thread, that listens for signals and acts accordingly. However, when I try to destroy the tkinter-GUI, the programm stops, and gives this error message:

> Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
> Python runtime state: initialized

I have recreated this minimum working example giving the same behavior:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading


class Gui(tk.Frame):
    """Minimal GUI with only a button"""
    def __init__(self, master: tk.Tk):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Spam').pack()


class Client:
    """Client for handling signals"""
    def __init__(self, master: tk.Tk):
        self.master = master
        self.gui = Gui(self.master)
        self.signal = None  # Initialize signal
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.listen_thread)
        self.running = True
        self.thread.start()

    def listen_thread(self):
        """Listen for signals and handle actions"""
        while self.running:
            signal = self.signal  # Dummy signal, set by external method, instead of received message from socket
            if signal == 'end':  # End signal received
                self.master.destroy()  # Destroy tkinter GUI, error occurs here
                self.running = False  # Terminate while loop
            else:
                time.sleep(0.2)


def send_signal_after(receiver: Client, delay: float = 2.0):
    """Send a signal to the client after short delay"""
    time.sleep(delay)
    receiver.signal = 'end'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    client = Client(root)
    threading.Thread(target=send_signal_after, args=(client,)).start()
    root.mainloop()
    if client.thread:  # Check if thread is still running, if so, wait for termination
        client.thread.join()
```

I am running this on MacOS 12.1, Python 3.10.

Is there any other way to terminate the application? I know, I could probably use *sys.exit()*, but I would like to do this in a cleaner way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, to understand how to do it, I made an example:

*This is the first file (the main one) :*

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import threading
import file2 as file2

def func(gui):
   # just some code around here

# start up the program
root = Tk()

# pass the root in the __init__ function from file2
mainGui = file2.file2Class(root)

# Start the new thread
theThread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=([mainGui]))
theThread.daemon = True
theThread.start()

# loop command
tk.mainloop()
```

*And this is file2 :*

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class file2Class:
    root = None
    def __init__(self, initialRoot):
        self.root = initialRoot
        self.createUI();

    def createUI(self):
        # This is an exit button
        tk.Button(
            self.root, 
            text="Exit",
            font = "Verdana 10 bold", 
            fg="red",
            command=self.root.destroy, # <- this is the exit command
            width=25,
            height=2).grid(row=0,column=0)
```

So, the most important thing is to make sure that you pass `root` in the `args` of the thread.

I hope I helped you!